# How to install Gimp Toolbox Photoshop Theme

Tags: themes, gimp, administrator

i want to unpack the zip file (from GIMP toolbox like Photoshop) to the path /usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/

but I need administrator rights to unpack that zip file. How can I proceed?

Link: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/GIMP+toolbox+like+Photoshop?content=159293

I am completely new in ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Put "sudo" in front of the command or ask your administrator if you are not.

Comment: You can probably put it in `~/.local/share/gimp/2.0/themes` as well.

Comment: It says `- Unzip the downloaded file into /home/{username}/.gimp-2.x/`

Comment: Indeed. @bain add as answer, if you can. It is better not to use `sudo` if one doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sudo unzip 159293-PSIcons1.1.zip -d /usr/share/gimp/2.0/themes/`.
`sudo` will give you the admin privileges after you enter your user password.

Comment: Where I have to paste that command?

Comment: Open a terminal with `crtl + alt + t` then use `cd ~/Downloads` to go to the folder to which you downloaded the file. replace `~/Downloads` if you downloaded it to a different folder.